# How to animate strength of displace modifier?

Tags: displacement

[image]

I want to animate the strength of displace modifier, from 0 to `-5.4`

I tried to select the second keyframe (#151) and change strength to -5.4.  But when I click play it does not work and strength is restored back to zero.

Comment: When you change the value on the second keyframe it's orange.  Press i on it to turn it yellow (add a second keyframe)